# Video not play in AVPlayer or safari but play in chrome

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, safari, avplayer

I have open AVPlayer to play the video by url link, but video not play in player and also not play in safari but video play on chrome browser.

My code is >>>>>>>>>

```
if url != nil  {
  let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
  player.allowsExternalPlayback = true
  let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
  playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
  player.play()
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a fix? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this >>>

```
 let player = AVPlayer(url: url) 
 player.rate = 1
 playerViewController.player = player
 playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame
 playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true
 addChild(playerViewController)
 self.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
 playerViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

It is work fine .